# How would you use AsyncTasks in a Utils/Helper class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-room, helper

Hi I've only recently started working with room DataBase and the course I was watching suggested using a Utils/helper class for all the database operations but I never was taught how you convert all of the utils static methods to Asynctasks for proper use in a Room DataBase so I'm wondering if anyone has advice on how to achive this. cheers

(below is the Utils and mainFragment I'm working with

[The Utils class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/730CX.png)

```java
package maddo.com.aquariumfish.MainFragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import maddo.com.aquariumfish.Adaptors.FishAdaptor;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.Daos.FishDao;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.DataBases.FishDataBase;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.FavouriteFishActivity;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.Models.Fish;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.R;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.SearchActivity;
import maddo.com.aquariumfish.Utils;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView MainRecView;

    private FishAdaptor fishAdaptor;




    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frangment_main,container,false);

        initView(view);
        initBottomNavView();
        initRecView();

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initRecView();
    }

    private void initRecView(){
        fishAdaptor = new FishAdaptor(getActivity());
        MainRecView.setAdapter(fishAdaptor);
        MainRecView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        ArrayList<Fish> fish = Utils.getAllFish(getActivity());
        if(null!= fish){
            fishAdaptor.setFish(fish);
        }



    }

    private void initBottomNavView() {

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bottomHome);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.bottomHome:
                        break;
                    case R.id.bottomFavFish:
                        Intent FavIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavouriteFishActivity.class);
                        FavIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(FavIntent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.search:
                        Intent SearchIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
                        SearchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(SearchIntent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }
    private void initView(View view) {
        MainRecView = view.findViewById(R.id.mainRecView);
         bottomNavigationView =view.findViewById(R.id.MainbottomNavView);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't want to convert EACH of the methods into an AsyncTask, if that is what you are saying. An AsyncTask is a framework for concurrency which allows you to make calls to your Utils class while on its own specialized thread.

If we want to make things as simple as possible just create an AsyncTask class and just call your Utils methods. the context your Utils methods would use would be that provided by the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AsyncTask, I will suggest to use coroutines. It is very simple and most efficient than AsyncTask.